# c++ - How can I use a structure to calculate the total number of males and females introduced?

Tags: c++, arrays, structure

I'm learning how to use structures.
I'm struggling to get it to work, actually the program is very large, but particularly in this part I need your help.
It doesn't count the total number of females or males, It shows "strange large numbers or only 0".
So if you can tell me what I'm doing wrong I'd really appreciate it.

Thanks.

```
    #include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct person
{

   int sex;
   int males; 
   int females;   
};

typedef struct person P;

int main()
{

int size=0;
cout<<"How many employees do you want to insert? "<<endl;
cin>>size;
P employee[size];
for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
{


    cout<<"\t1.Male\t2.Female"<<endl;
    cin>>employee[i].sex;
    if (employee[i].sex==1)
{
    employee[i].males++;
}
else
{
    employee[i].females++;
}
cout<<"\n\n* * * * * *\n\n";
}



for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
{

cout<<"Male employees: = "<<employee[i].males<<endl;
cout<<"Female employees: "<<employee[i].females<<endl;
}


system ("pause");
return 0;}
```

Comment: 1) `P employee[size];` is not valid C++ - variable-length arrays are a GCC extension; 2) `employee[i].males++;` is using `employee[i].males` uninitialized; 3) shouldn't you have one male and one female count for the whole program rather than one count *per person*?

Comment: Why do you even need the `person` structure? All you need are two `int`s, one for counting each sex. Increment them conditionally depending on user input, and you have your answer.

Comment: @Praetorian This is an example of [reduced code making zero sense](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269476/questions-that-dont-provide-real-code).

Answer (score 1):

The issue you are having is because you didn't initiate the values to 0 for your employee[] array. When you declared the array employee[], your OS automatically give each of the .sex, .male, .female a location of memory inside the computer, which was previously filled with other random integers. Whenever you declare an array like the on you did, you should create a loop that initializes all the variables to zero, such as:

```
for (int i = 0; i<size; i++)
{
  employee[i].sex = 0;
  employee[i].male = 0;
  employee[i].female = 0;
}
```

You should do that right after declaring your employee array. That should solve your problem.

Edit: Another issue your having is that you are not outputting the right information. Your final code just outputs employee[i].male and female for every case of 'i', so the values obtained would always be 1 and 0. If you want to see how many are female or male for instance, you should declare a separate integer value, initiate it to zero, and create an if conditional that will increase the male or female integer value by 1 every time an employee is male or female respectively

Comment: I'd say a better solution is adding a default constructor to the `person` struct that initializes the members to zero. And those members seem unnecessary. He just needs one, `sex`, which can be 0 or 1 for male/female, or use enums. And then count them at the end.

Comment: I agree with the option of a constructor, and I agree with the option of having the variables in the manner you suggested, however he wanted to know what was wrong with his code, regardless if it was poorly designed or not. His intention of learning to use structs was also stated, hence jumping to constructors might defeat the purpose of just practicing one topic at a time.

Comment: Right, I agree with all of that. But what we typically do around here is explain the errors, and then post a better/alternate way to do it, if there is one.

Comment: @Praetorian I'd claim that the better solution, if we are using an array, is to simply initialize the array with `= { };`. The non-standard VLA seems to foil my plot on clang, though.

Comment: @Praetorian: I prefer not to go about giving only 1 type of 'typical' answer to all questions given. Rather I prefer to provide the most productive answer depending on what the users needs are. That's my preferred methodology and in my opinion the better approach, not hating though xD

Answer (score 1):

> It shows "strange large numbers or only 0".

Here's what the standard has to say about uninitialized values.

> § 8.5/11
>
> If no initializer is specified for an object, the object is
>   default-initialized; if no initialization is performed, an object with
>   automatic or dynamic storage duration has **indeterminate value.**

...

> § 8.5/6
>
> To default-initialize an object of type T means:
>
> — if T is a
>   (possibly cv-qualified) class type (Clause 9), the default constructor
>   for T is called (and the initialization is ill-formed if T has no
>   accessible default constructor);
>
> — if T is an array type, each element is default-initialized;
>
> — otherwise, **no initialization is performed.**
>
> If a program calls for the default initialization of an object of a
>   const-qualified type T, T shall be a class type with a user-provided
>   default constructor.

This indeterminate value could be as you said, strange large numbers or only zero.